# Password Field Modification with React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

I am trying to build a new kind of password field, the differentiating factor would be when moving the text-cursor in the password field, it should unmask the character at the same index as the text cursor. I have tried various methods but couldn't quite build it. Can someone help?

I have tried a text field and masking it with css, and it works but not entirely.

Comment: `I have tried various methods` are any of these various methods even close to what you want? show some of these various methods

Comment: Please provide the code that you tried the one which is not working